# Confusion regarding product of two lie groups and the generators

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Being a physicist and only just been introduced to group theory, please forgive my lack of rigour.

I have some confusion regarding Lie groups and Lie algebras, and I want to understand the following example - the addition of angular momentum of two spin $1/2$ particles.

Each Spin-half particle represented by $|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ and $|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$. These furnish a representation of the group $SU(2)$. In a sense, the addition of angular momentum, is nothing but $SU(2) \otimes SU(2)$. This is because, in order to add the angular momenta, I must construct a larger hilbert space using a tensor product of the two smaller hilbert spaces of the individual spins.

Now, I've also read that a tensor product of Lie Groups is equivalent to a direct sum of lie Algebras.
Hence, $$SU(2)\otimes SU(2) \equiv su(2) \oplus su(2)$$

However the lie algebra is represented by the generators of $SU(2)$, and the above line leads me to believe that if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the two generators of the two $SU(2)$ groups, then the generator for the combined group should be $G_1\oplus G_2$.

However, from angular momentum algebra, we know that :

$$SU(2)\otimes SU(2) \sim (I_1+G_1)\otimes(I_2+G_2)\sim I_1\otimes I_2 +(I_1\otimes G_2+G_1\otimes I_2)$$

Hence, the new generator of the larger hilbert space, seems to be $$(I_1\otimes G_2+G_1\otimes I_2) \ne G_1\oplus G_2$$

Then what does $su(2) \oplus su(2)$ mean in terms of the generators ? Can someone please explain, where I'm going wrong with the above example ?

Regards.

Comment: I would hesitate to say any Lie group is equivalent to a Lie algebra. What you want to say specifically is that the Lie algebra of $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ (note just a direct product rather than a tensor product) is $\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$

Comment: @Callum what is the implication for the generators then ? If I do create a group by the direct product of the $SU(2)$'s, what will the generators of the new group look like ? Also, I do think that I'm using the words group and representations interchangebly.

Comment: You have to learn a bit more Lie group theory before you can formulate a well-posed question. For instance, the last sentence can be made into a reasonable question but it will be about Lie algebras, not Lie groups.